# Django template in nested dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I am using Django template, and I met one problem with nested dictionary.

Dict:

```
result_dict = {'type_0' : {'file_name' : 'abc', 'count' : 0},
               'type_1' : {'file_name' : 'xyz', 'count' : 50}}
```

and the template in my HTML file is:

```
{% for type in result_dict %}
    {{ type }}, {{ type.file_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I show the value of type_0 and type_1 only ?

I've tried:

```
{% for key, value in result_dict %}
    {{ key }}, {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dict.items`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#dict.items) or [`dict.values`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#dict.values):

```
{% for key, value in result_dict.items %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Example in interactive shell:

```
>>> result_dict = {'type_0' : {'file_name' : 'abc', 'count' : 0},
...                'type_1' : {'file_name' : 'xyz', 'count' : 50}}
>>>
>>> t = Template('''
... {% for key, value in result_dict.items %}
...     {{ value }}
... {% endfor %}
... ''')
>>> print(t.render(Context({'result_dict': result_dict})))


    {&#39;count&#39;: 50, &#39;file_name&#39;: &#39;xyz&#39;}

    {&#39;count&#39;: 0, &#39;file_name&#39;: &#39;abc&#39;}
```

---

```
>>> t = Template('''
... {% for key, value in result_dict.items %}
...     {{ value|safe }}
... {% endfor %}
... ''')
>>> print(t.render(Context({'result_dict': result_dict})))


    {'count': 50, 'file_name': 'xyz'}

    {'count': 0, 'file_name': 'abc'}
```

Comment: How would he access a value inside the nested dict? E.g. `{{ value.file_name }}`?

Comment: @RobertGrant, Yes, it is. Why don't you test in the django shell? The above example was copied from django shell.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually asking for someone else in the sopython chat room :) On a laptop with no Python. Sad times.