# get dictionary value by key in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a dictionary like this :

```
myDict = {key1: item1,
          key2: item2}
```

How can I get **item1** by providing **key1** in django template and more if I have a nested dict like this:

```
myDict2 = {key1: {key11: item11,
                  key12: item12},
           key2: {key21: item21,
                  key22: item22}}
```

for example how can I get `item22` using `key22`

I know `{{  myDict[key1] }}` doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is to look at the solution at [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable) and then apply the filter twice.

```
{{ myDict2|get_item:"key2"|get_item:"key22"}}
```

A longer answer (taken heavily from the answer I linked to) is:

1. **Create a folder template_tags in your app folder**
2. **Create a file in that folder custom_tags.py**
3. **In custom_tags.py have this code from the other answer:**

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

4. **In settings register your custom tags, add the libraries and leave the rest of the TEMPLATES alone.**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...   
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [   
            ],

            'libraries': {
            'custom_tags':'YOURAPP.template_tags.custom_tags'
            }
        },
    },
]
```

5. **In your template:**

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{{ myDict2|get_item:"key2"|get_item:"key22"}}
```

Comment: Thanks Zev , I guess I checked the link you've mentioned 50 times but I couldn't figure out how to call get_item twice; {{ myDict2|get_item:"key2"|get_item:"key22"}} is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Typically to iterate through a dict in a template something like this...

```
{% for key, value in harvest_data.items %}
    {{ key }} <br>
    {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
        {{ key2 }} <br>
        {% for key3, value3 in value2.items %}
            {{ key3 }}:{{ value3 }} <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

With regard to the nested dict rendering in templates I think this is answered here

[Django template in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623013/django-template-in-nested-dictionary)

Comment: Thanks Paddy, since I have the exact key I don't intend to use for loop